# In "феминизм такой феминизм" - what does "такой" mean?

Tags: лексикон

I found the phrase "Феминизм такой феминизм" on an online forum and I'm wondering what такой means here? The only translation I can think of is "feminism, oh feminism" but i dont know.

Comment: Feminism be feminism or Feminism is such Feminism

Comment: Detailed explanation here: [X is so X](http://lurkmore.to/X_is_so_X) (in Russian).

Comment: @Alexander you should make it an answer.

Comment: @Alexander Your link is blocked by some Russian Internet providers (incl. mine).

Comment: @Alex_ander Sorry to hear that. [How to access "lurkmore" site](https://roscenzura.com/threads/535/)

Comment: It is an Internet meme

Answer (score 12):

**Такой** means **such**. The main point is not what такой means, but why the other word is repeated.

**Feminism is such feminism.** In this phrase the second repeated word replaces a normal adjective there. It's done for emphasys and understatement implying the author's attitude to the phenomenon named by the repeated word.

Normally it could be, for example,

> Феминизм такой глупый!
>   Феминизм такой бессмысленный!
>   Феминизм такой
>   категоричный!
>   Феминизм такой странный!

depending on the context, or leaving you room to think.

It's a fashionable pattern now. :) Like девочки - такие девочки! Instead of девочки такие капризные/странные/жеманные/непоследовательные!

Comment: Актрисы — такие актрисы

Answer (score 2):

It's an *informal* expression of disapproval lying somewhere between the more formal **feminism at its worst** and the informal **feminism bloody feminism**. Similar Russian expressions: *махровый такой феминизм, этакий пещерный феминизм (матриархат, домострой)*.

Answer (score 2):

Such is the feminism, at its "best".